# Magento Migration

Tags: magento-1.9

I have been asked to migrate magento from another host, been pulling my hair out on one module that will not load, which gives the following PHP error.

PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Mage_Megamenupro_Helper_Data' not found in

The module xml file looks like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <EM_Megamenupro>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </EM_Megamenupro>
    </modules>
</config>
```

The module files are found here:

app/code/local/EM/Megamenupro/

```
├── Block
│   ├── Adminhtml
│   │   ├── Megamenupro
│   │   │   ├── Edit
│   │   │   │   ├── Form.php
│   │   │   │   ├── Tab
│   │   │   │   │   └── Form.php
│   │   │   │   └── Tabs.php
│   │   │   ├── Edit.php
│   │   │   └── Grid.php
│   │   ├── Megamenupro.php
│   │   ├── Menueditor
│   │   │   ├── Edit.php
│   │   │   └── Sample.php
│   │   ├── Menueditor.php
│   │   ├── Renderer
│   │   │   └── Description.php
│   │   └── Variable.php
│   ├── Catalognavigation.php
│   └── Megamenupro.php
├── controllers
│   ├── Adminhtml
│   │   ├── MegamenuproController.php
│   │   └── MenueditorController.php
│   └── IndexController.php
├── etc
│   ├── config.xml
│   └── widget.xml
├── Helper
│   ├── Cache.php
│   ├── Data.php
│   └── Multicache.php
├── Model
│   ├── Megamenupro.php
│   ├── Mysql4
│   │   ├── Megamenupro
│   │   │   └── Collection.php
│   │   └── Megamenupro.php
│   ├── Resource
│   │   └── Category
│   │       └── Flat.php
│   ├── Status.php
│   └── Update.php
└── sql
    └── megamenupro_setup
        ├── mysql4-install-0.1.1.php
        ├── mysql4-install-1.0.0.php
        ├── mysql4-upgrade-0.1.0-0.1.1.php
        └── mysql4-upgrade-0.1.1-1.0.0.php
```

for the life of me I cant figure where its calling the wrong module.

Comment: Have you tried to disable compilation and then enable it again, something this can happen when magento gets abit mixed up

Comment: Is there a file in `app/etc/modules` for the extension? Should be something like `EM_Megamenupro.xml`.

Answer (score 1):

That helper class is called auto-magically in magento, there doesn't have to be an explicit call to it in any other php class or xml. But there could be a phtml or local.xml that is using it, and that is why it's kicking the error.  I think you should just create that file in the offending module, leave the class's content blank and call it a day.

Answer (score 0):

No one can tell you why this error is there but you can **check this check list** to make sure those are things were there

1) login admin panel goto `system->configuration->Advanced->Advanced` and make sure `EM_Megamenupro` should be enable

2) goto `app/etc/modules/MEM_Megamenupro.xml` and make sure

```
 <EM_Megamenupro>
     <active>true</active>
     <codePool>core</codePool>
 </EM_Megamenupro>
```

this node should be true.

3) check for compilation, if compilation is enable then disable compile and check. and it works then do recompile. for compilation go to `system->tool->compilation`

4) also check `app/code/community OR local /EM/Megamenupro/Helper/Data.php` exist or not.

Comment: Thank for the input, those things I have already tried. I dug into the templates and found that $helper = Mage::helper("megamenupro"), is what causing magento to error out. The modules XML file for helpers are correct to the reference of the class.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time when I had this issue, it was because a `module="..."` node in a XML file hat the wrong value. I would double-check the `widget.xml` file. Maybe it helps if you remove the occurrences of `module="..."` there as a test.